# SQL Server: Copy rows of table to same table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables with data: GroupTable and PeopleTable.

GroupTable has this columns: id, continent, country

PeopleTable has this columns: id, groupId , name

groupId is a foreign key to GroupTable.id

Both tables are already populated from my application. What I want to do is create a stored procedure to copy contents of both tables to the same tables but changing the `continent` column of GroupTable. So the new rows in PeopleTable will point to the new rows in GroupTable. Input for the stored procedure are @sourceCont, @destinationCont

What I have:

```
GroupTable:
      id   |    continent   |   company
       0   |    europe      |     aa
       1   |    europe      |    bb
       2   |    europe      |    cc

PeopleTable:
      id   |   groupId    |   name
      0    |      0       |   John
      1    |      0       |   Mary
      2    |      0       |   Nick
      3    |      1       |   Peter
      4    |      2       |   Michel
```

This is what I want (@sourceCont = europe, @destinationCont = america)

```
GroupTable:
      id   |    continent   |   company
       0   |    europe      |    aa
       1   |    europe      |    bb
       2   |    europe      |    cc
       3   |    america     |    aa
       4   |    america     |    bb
       5   |    america     |    cc
PeopleTable:
      id   |   groupId    |   name
      0    |      0       |   John
      1    |      0       |   Mary
      2    |      0       |   Nick
      3    |      1       |   Peter
      4    |      2       |   Michel
      5    |      3       |   John
      6    |      3       |   Mary
      7    |      3       |   Nick
      8    |      4       |   Peter
      9    |      5       |   Michel
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server  ....  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE Proc Rocount
@sourceCont NVARCHAR(50), @destinationCont NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @String_sql NVARCHAR(MAX),@Maxid INT

     --NOTE IF GroupID Is AUto Generated IN GroupTable
    SET @String_sql='Insert INTO GroupTable
                     SELECT '''+@destinationCont+''' FROM GroupTable WHERE continent ='''+@sourceCont+''' '
    PRINT @String_sql
    EXEC (@String_sql)

    SELECT @Maxid= ID FROM GroupTable WHERE  continent = @destinationCont

    SET @String_sql='Insert INTO PeopleTable
                     SELECT ID,'''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),@Maxid)+''',name 
                     FROM PeopleTable WHERE GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM GroupTable WHERE continent ='''+@sourceCont+''')'
    PRINT @String_sql
    EXEC (@String_sql)




END
```

Comment: Basically you wan't to create a replica for new Group which is depend on existing group.and same for PeopleTable.And is GroupId Auto increment

Comment: @aggicd I Had Updated The Ans check it